# GCP is killing nodes, where my one and only frontend and database pods are lying in

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, google-cloud-platform

My app is running in google cloud platform(GCP) and containers are running inside kubernetes.

The problem:
When cloud platform is down-scaling nodes, it kills nodes, where my one and only database and frontend pods are lying in.

Question:
How to stop GCP killing nodes, where my only frontend and database pods are inside?

Comment: I think you can set the number of minimum replicas, but Pod are designed to be killable in nature, the lifecycle of Pods are typically independent of the lifecycle of databases / persistent storages.

Comment: The kubernetes is handling down-scaling pretty good. No problem with that. I think the problem is in google cloud platform side, that it kills nodes, which have the less cpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem by myself.

All my frontend, backend, database and redis containers were in the same nodepool. When i separeted them into different nodepools everything started working.

Creating node selector:
adding into the end of backend-deployment.yaml
  nodeSelector:
          cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: backend

More info:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/blob/release-1.3/docs/user-guide/node-selection/index.md